# Python Regex: How to print the entire word that matches a string using the number keyword?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, findall

I want to print the whole words that match the given string using the number keyword but it only prints numbers.
Could anyone help with this?

```
import re
string = ''' '%SYSDB-SYSDB-6-TIMEOUT_EDM', 
'%HA-HA_WD-3-DISK_ALARM_ALERT', 
'%ROUTING-FIB-4-RETRYDB_NONEMPTY', 
'%SYSDB-SYSDB-6-TIMEOUT_EDM', 
'%HA-HA_WD-3-DISK_ALARM_ALERT', 
'%ROUTING-FIB-4-RETRYDB_NONEMPTY'
'''
output = re.findall(r"-[1-4]-", string)
print(output)
```

**Current Output**
['-3-', '-4-', '-3-', '-4-']

**Expected Output:**

```
['%HA-HA_WD-3-DISK_ALARM_ALERT',
'%HA-HA_WD-3-DISK_ALARM_ALERT',
'%ROUTING-FIB-4-RETRYDB_NONEMPTY',
'%ROUTING-FIB-4-RETRYDB_NONEMPTY']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enclose your string with `[` and `]`, then use `ast` to cast the result to a string list, and then filter that list with your regex:

```py
import re, ast
s = ''' '%SYSDB-SYSDB-6-TIMEOUT_EDM', 
'%HA-HA_WD-3-DISK_ALARM_ALERT', 
'%ROUTING-FIB-4-RETRYDB_NONEMPTY', 
'%SYSDB-SYSDB-6-TIMEOUT_EDM', 
'%HA-HA_WD-3-DISK_ALARM_ALERT', 
'%ROUTING-FIB-4-RETRYDB_NONEMPTY'
'''
l = ast.literal_eval(f'[{s}]')
rx = re.compile(r"-[1-4]-")
print(list(filter(rx.search, l)))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/oDhh0w).

Output:

```
[
    '%HA-HA_WD-3-DISK_ALARM_ALERT', 
    '%ROUTING-FIB-4-RETRYDB_NONEMPTY',
    '%HA-HA_WD-3-DISK_ALARM_ALERT', 
    '%ROUTING-FIB-4-RETRYDB_NONEMPTY'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups in your regex:

```
output = re.findall(r"'(.+-[1-4]-.+)'", string)
```

Edit:
E.g.:

```
import re
string = ''' '%SYSDB-SYSDB-6-TIMEOUT_EDM', 
'%HA-HA_WD-3-DISK_ALARM_ALERT', 
'%ROUTING-FIB-4-RETRYDB_NONEMPTY', 
'%SYSDB-SYSDB-6-TIMEOUT_EDM', 
'%HA-HA_WD-3-DISK_ALARM_ALERT', 
'%ROUTING-FIB-4-RETRYDB_NONEMPTY'
'''
#output = re.findall(r"-[1-4]-", string)
output = re.findall(r"'(.+-[1-4]-.+)'", string)
print(output)
```

gives:

```
[
     '%HA-HA_WD-3-DISK_ALARM_ALERT', 
     '%ROUTING-FIB-4-RETRYDB_NONEMPTY',
     '%HA-HA_WD-3-DISK_ALARM_ALERT',
     '%ROUTING-FIB-4-RETRYDB_NONEMPTY'
]
```